# Is it possible to use the Realm database in an iOS Swift app with openCv?

Tags: swift, opencv, realm

I have an app in Swift 4 using openCV shape recognition and I want to now store all the shapes in a database. With all the confusion with bridging headers, wrappers and so forth in order to get openCV going in Swift at all I wonder whether I now could somehow integrate Realm into this scenario, especially considering that all the shape data is generated in my .mm file in Objective C (so, far away from my usual easy set up of Realm with Swift). Any suggestions about how this could be done or whether there is an example somewhere already are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible and I tested it for Xcode 8.3 to 10 and Swift 3.2 and 4 in conjunction with Realm 3.11 and openCV 3.4. The trick is to get all the data from the Wrapper back into Swift and back.